# Nested Requirements for Tree Data Structure with heterogeneous Nodes

Tags: c++, tree, c++20, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

**Objective:**

I want to implement a tree data structure with non-identical nodes to manage my data. In general, the tree consists of 2 different type of nodes, namely, "Nodes" and "LeafNodes". Those nodes which have no children are considered to be "LeafNodes", which will be used to store data. Within the tree all nodes are tagged with metadata. The tree must be created at compile-time.

**How:**

My current implementation uses type template parameters to tag all nodes with metadata. The concept "Header" is used to specify the requirements of a header-type. If the node isn't a specialization of "LeafNode", "Nodes/LeafNodes" specializations are passed to specify the children of that node. The concept "Nodelike" is used to indicate how a specialization of "Node/LeafNode" has to look like.

**Error:**

I get a template constraint failure when specifying my tree type

```
using Tree = Node <
    Header0<0>,
    LeafNode<Header1<0,20,5>>,
    LeafNode<Header1<1,20,'f'>>,
    LeafNode<Header1<2,20,4.4>>
>;
```

Unfortunately, I can't interpret the compiler error so that I have no hint how to resolve the error. I am using the compiler "x86-64 gcc 12" with the following flags "-std=c++20 -O3". Here is the not working online code: [Code](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAA7FykAA6oCoRODB7evnppGY4CoeFRLLHxAGyVtpj2RQxCBEzEBDk%2BfoF2mA5ZTS0EJZExcYnJCs2t7Xnjk4Nhw%2BWj1QCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BYcjeWADUJv5uLcRMAJ5n2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2BfIE/iCdw/PZn2DEOXhOZzcTgmxEwrD%2BTxewLeHzcBC8KXocIBQJBYPOYUyYjwAC84gB9Wh4CaYhE497gtDAzApAgKamA16gunnAjXFKYUkEK6EVn%2Be7wp5eDJGY7MNgKFJMbbHb5nKzi55PAiYFjopha%2BkGBQKY4AFUxDO2zOOwRhVAAEjCsMQPgARY7QgCOXjw0ONEBWJgSasex1DpyDJpAIAAki7A26ALR3Y4MgBucUc0XoAtQ4O9ggAHAK/v5g2HwxZIyAMiT48ck6KUwJ0608Fn%2BURwTWOyWy2Gq%2BgAGpiLyYVX/ePj9VanUGfWfQ3Gs2i/4WpkEY4RDCYB1MJ2u92YL0%2BzB%2BgNB/7lwOVqOxusN7BNhgtzPZzvnfMEIsEXsThJx0sJ01bVdXnNxDiYI1TXNARLQ3Xd9zON0tywBC4nBZdH0DNxsOtW00OIDDf2nEC5zHBdIKXGDGStFDMFCABrLk3U9b1fQgE1zz7UNKVJVBom0HoCFJVMiJXQCnnLViTyXKMCKnDVnn/BSgMeGdQPItwbSYe1HTiY47UxKEvAcPCdLo44aGYWhr1U8sAHp7OOAAlU8Ni2d55MksMJj1PBkCfCZMFUFJnTtY4ED0wiL2UiTFIcpzowYXzGVZbzQ0lMJgGOHk%2BQPXLGFYTyowKlTYuDf51LI8E6IIgzSE3bdGMwAA6NrNyMwUTI3OjbPS5VmkcAKGSCkKwoiqLbPKy8w1RdFNIiNqWuTZAEDodARQq%2BFppI2c9U0z9v2OaMGu%2BKNuwFY4hAapgvCIY5B064huoMqKuD6kMfMG/zAq1MbjkOy7YwPaMFPLXyht%2B4LQuVYkO1hkkDyEMGw0y6UCoPLBDgKiBBwDOLwe%2B4aBFGmGMaHEdmIesqAK2tTSP2vMwi/IGnpegiNA%2Bwm/OJ5K/phwGN2BpDjtVU5ttp1T/jR7KTWhKmLPBGbQw58FOdFUhlbMqhevOAj3vODRSDMI2AFYS2wTX%2Bu0nXt3BfXwWSE3SDADgqFdi2rc%2B0Mbd1twHfOMxjaNyQWskC2J3EunmeOFgmDCf0uf7eWcppjg1loThTd4PwOC0UhUE4HDLGsZV3KVPYeFIAhNHTtYGJASQAE4Wq4fwCwLSpJA0LgEibpupBqTOOEkHPa4LzheAUEAjZrvP09IOBYBgRAQA2AgUju8hKDQHU6DiCIis4VRO4TLvjmAZAAq4MwWrMXhMHwIhiDwdA9H4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUOoeepBdDJAAO5XBSJwHgGcs5j2AYXDgAB5O6m8NyoCoMcE%2BlQz6SAvlfY4N877HAgB4Pe9BnSVxWLwOeWgVj10brfU2TcCzdwLMwjQ/gEiVASPoTgo9SAsBAKbI2ud86IKnjPautc1hL1XrvFI%2B8yAUAgAopRIBgA3yDjQWgWpiDTwgNEce0QwgtGuNA3gu82CCCQQwWg5jgFYDjkYcQjiTy9HTNPYBwUeh3R2PnZmdRx4UmiFcYg1wPBYHHoKPAQjuALyoAYYAChBx4EwGApBfJc5Vw/sIUQ4hf65IAWoceoD9CGGMNYaw%2Bg2zT0gGsVAzIsheITCqfwLpTAl0sCbesSD/BTzqEJLILgGDuE8B0PQIQFhlAqPkdImQBDTD8MkAoCyGBDBmaMcYgzegCH6FMcZMxaj1D6HMDZIx4izAGEsvQvlWjnKWJctYChy4/2rvLCxsCODZ1IGI3giDsG4PwdfW%2BZgSHFysJYBquBCAkFOICZIxwyGKIofC/wXBqHSPnvQ0gkU9yjH9HwkevAhEiN%2BePCRtgpG0LrqQBuIiWqdy4G3ZhBYTYaHYdIYe/TyUIMnliuhXz768vEfymlOKWwZGcJIIAA%3D)

**Implementation:**

```
using namespace std;


template<class T>
concept LeafHeader = requires (){
    {T::ID} -> convertible_to<uint8_t>;
    {T::size} -> convertible_to<size_t>;
    T::dValue;
};

template<class T>
concept NodeHeader = requires (){
    {T::ID} -> convertible_to<uint8_t>;
};

template<class T>
concept Header = NodeHeader<T> || LeafHeader<T>;

template<class T>
concept NodeLike = requires(T){
    is_object_v<T>;
    requires T::Header;

};


template<LeafHeader H>
struct LeafNode final{

    // Resource Header
    static constexpr H header{};

    // Instances
    using type = typename H::type;
};

template<NodeHeader H, NodeLike... N>
struct Node{
    static constexpr H header{};
    tuple<N...> childs;

};

template<uint8_t I, std::size_t S, auto V>
struct Header1{
    static constexpr uint8_t ID = I;
    static constexpr size_t size = S;
    using type = decltype(V);
    static constexpr type dValue = V;
};

template<uint8_t I>
struct Header0{
    static constexpr uint8_t ID = I; 
};


using Tree = Node <
    Header0<0>,
    LeafNode<Header1<0,20,5>>,
    LeafNode<Header1<1,20,'f'>>,
    LeafNode<Header1<2,20,4.4>>
>;

int main(){
    Tree t;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the definition of the `NodeLike`:

```
template<class T>
concept NodeLike = requires(T) {
  is_object_v<T>;
  requires T::Header;
};
```

First, the `requires`-clause only checks the validity of the expression, so `is_object_v<T>` is useless here because it is always valid, you should use the nested `requires`, but it is more appropriate just to move it outside the `requires`-clause.

Second, `requires T::Header` is not satisfied in your case, because class `Node` does not have a static variable named `Header` (but `header`, I suspect it's a typo), and since you're using the nested-`requires`, `T::Header` will be evaluated, which is never satisfied because the variable cannot be converted to `bool`.

You can just use `T::header` to check if `T` has a static variable named `header`, so this should work:

```
template<class T>
concept NodeLike = is_object_v<T> && requires { T::header; };
```